# Hide preloaded state in .js file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, isomorphic-javascript

When I do SSR in my React apps (using Node.js / Express), and using Redux for state, I always end up with a similar to `window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = {....}`

This output is something rendered together with the generated html code from `renderToString` but I'm wondering if there is a way to get that preloaded state variable inside a "virtual" js file instead (that can be referenced in my main layout template file), just to make the source code cleaner, without having to do the same rendering process twice?

I currently do my SSR via a middleware that I've setup in my Node.js/Express app.

Anyone has any ideas or recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean if you can somehow import it into your `Layout.js` file and bundle it at compile time? I think you have to make it a global variable as it is injected into the document at runtime.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would just be cool to be able to set it as a valid virtual path inside my middleware somehow, and that path is the one I reference in my Layout file.... I know it would be possible to write it to a file, but that would be too slow.

Comment: @Tholle or not my Layout.js, but my Layout.hbs, the main layout file that will be rendered via Express (which also includes the React app bundle .js file)

Comment: Alright, interesting. I'm not sure if it's possible, but if it turns out to be impossible, you shouldn't feel too bad about it since a global variable containing the initial state is the standard way of going about it.

Comment: @Tholle Haha alright, it is just a matter of making the source code look a bit cleaner. Will see if anyone else has any ideas. Thanks